# Change .git folder path with --separate-git-dir twice / undoing the change

Tags: git

```
cd project
git init
mv .git ../tmp/project/.git
git init --separate-git-dir ../tmp/project/.git
```

Until here it works fine.

Then how about if you want to change location of the .git folder again ?
The following throws error :

```
mv ../tmp/project/.git ../tmp/project2/.git
git init --separate-git-dir ../tmp/project2/.git
```

Then how can we change the location again ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, actually `--separate-git-dir` creates a `.git` symlink in the working directory so basically we would just need to remove it before using the command again.

```
rm .git
git init --separate-git-dir ../tmp/project2/.git
```